# How to cache specific routes or remove from cache specific routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching, websocket

The fact is that I am connecting to sockets from another domain and have been trying for a long time to find out why I get 419 error when connecting to a private channel. It turns out that the csrf token is cached and I can successfully connect when the routes are not cached.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a way to be selective about it but try running:

- `php artisan route:cache`
- `php artisan cache:clear`

Or for the whole set of cache clears you can run `php artisan optimize`

The other option would be to wait out the cache expiry but I doubt you would want to do that!

Comment: It is the "php artisan route: cache" command that caches what I don't need.
It is in "php artisan optimize" list.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` will clear the route cache completely if that is what you want